# Обработка неправильного ввода пользователя

Tags: c++, исключения

В моей программе нужно обработать исключение,что ввёденное значение типа данных некорректно.Для моего случая мне надо,чтобы был ответ когда пользователь вместо значение типа double вводит тип string и в этом случае в консоли появляется сообщение "Вы ввели не корректно данные".Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cin.fail() делает такую проверку, можно написать так:

```
if(cin.fail()) {
  std::cin.clear();
  std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

прочитайте про защиту от неправильного ввода